# Wrong result using GLSL to convert YUV to RGB

Tags: c++, opengl, yuv

I'm writing shaders to display yuv images in my video playback project https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV. The shader seems right because I have tested on a single yuv image. But the result is always wrong if I apply my shader in GLWidgetRenderer.

The first image displayed without my shader. 2nd one is the result when using shader. For some video the result likes 3rd image, with many green lines.

I think there's some mistakes in my C++ code. But I can't find out them because I'm not very familar with OpenGL

So what may the reason be?

c++ code is here: https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/blob/master/src/GLWidgetRenderer.cpp

yuv 2 rgb shader https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/blob/master/src/shaders/yuv_rgb.f.glsl:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
// Set default precision to medium
precision mediump int;
precision mediump float;
#else
#define highp
#define mediump
#define lowp
#endif

// u_TextureN: yuv. use array?
uniform sampler2D u_Texture0;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture1;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture2;
varying lowp vec2 v_TexCoords;

//http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV calculation used
//http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php
//GLSL: col first
// use bt601
const mat4 colorMatrix = mat4(1, 1, 1, 0,
                              0, -0.344, 1.773, 0,
                              1.403, -0.714, 0, 0,
                              0, 0, 0, 1)
                        * mat4(1, 0, 0, 0,
                               0, 1, 0, 0,
                               0, 0, 1, 0,
                               0, -0.5, -0.5, 1);
void main()
{
    // use r, g, a to work for both yv12 and nv12
    gl_FragColor = clamp(colorMatrix* vec4(texture2D(u_Texture0, v_TexCoords).r,
                                           texture2D(u_Texture1, v_TexCoords).g,
                                           texture2D(u_Texture2, v_TexCoords).a,
                                           1)
                      , 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

[image: original image]

[image: yuv2rgb shader result]

[image: yuv2rgb shader result even worse]

Comment: I have fixed the issue. My mistake. The textures are created with wrong sizes. But green lines still exists in some video

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of the YUV input - is it planar data (in separate buffers) as expected by the shader ? Also the matrices do not seem right - have you referred to already existing examples in gstreamer, or for example in http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=25877

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: YUV420 planar, 3 planes. I think the shader and the matrix are right. I decode the same video and save each plane, and use `cat` to generate a yuv image. I test my shader for this image and the result image is right.

Comment: If this result is right - is the image that you posted as the original question from another shader that is not working ? What is the difference in the setups ?